# Are there any iOS Particle System Libraries

Tags: ios, particles, visualizer, particle-system

Does anyone know of any (opensource would be nice) Particle / Emitter libraries for iOS? I know of cocos iphone but couldn't find any others.

If all else fails I'll get my hands dirty and learn OpenGL but any helper libraries would be handy :)

Answer (score 1):

We used Pyro Particles http://pyro.fenomen-games.com/ in a couple games we ported from Mac and Windows.

Comment: Although it supports iPhone, it looks like the Pyro editor iteself only runs on Windows.  I haven't installed it yet, but it claims a static library for use in both the iOS Sim and Device.